# Sorted List in Java with elements of same value but different identity

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I know there are dozens of questions similar to this one, but I couldn't find an answer to my specific problem. Sorry if I missed it - please tell me where to look if it exists!

The problem seems very common to me: I need a list of objects that is sorted by some property of the object, and only have each object once in the list. Specifically, I am implementing A* path finding and need the open list sorted by the F-values of the nodes.

What I tried was using a TreeSet with a Comparator that compares the f-values of two Nodes, like this:

```
public class NodeFComparator implements Comparator<Node> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Node arg0, Node arg1) {
        return (arg0.getF() - arg1.getF());
    }

}
```

Class Node is looking like this :

```
public class Node {

    PathableMap parentmap;
    Point coord;    // coordinates on the map
    private Node parent;    // parent node: used by astar to backtrace shortest path

    (etc etc)

    /*
     * F-value of a node is the sum of the distance from start + distance to target.
     * The nodes are searched in the order of that value.
     */
    public int getF() {
        return getG() + getH();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 65537;
        return prime * coord.x + coord.y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (coord == null) {
            if (other.coord != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!coord.equals(other.coord))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

The problem with this solution seems to be that if two different nodes have the same f-value (which happens all the time), in other words the comparator returns 0, the TreeSet seems to treat that as Node1 == Node2 and doesn't add the second node to the list or does some other weird thing because my openlist misses nodes that should be there.

So the only way I can think of doing this with the existing classes is to use a simple ArrayList and sort it each time I append a Node to it.

Is there really no collection class in Java or Apache Commons that:

- keeps a sorted list of objects by any property of an object
- has fast lookup and insert times
- is as easy to use as other collection classes?

I'm puzzled.

Comment: What class Node is? If it is your custom, do you implement equals/hashCode contract correctly?

Comment: Node is pretty complicated, I append a short version of it to the question.

Comment: If you add a second comparison if getF() are equal to the other getF() then it should solve your problem. There you can use the .toString() and compare it to the others .toString()

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add node to.

Comment: @user: sounds easy and interesting. will try. thx.

Comment: @jackthehipster instead of `toString`, try `hashCode`

Comment: Why would you use a set when you need duplicate values, when a set is specifically designed to exclude them? A* is typically defined using a priority queue, and Java includes a `PriorityQueue` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a set if you want to have elements that compare equal (in this case, that have the same f-value). The A* algorithm is typically defined with respect to a priority queue, and as of Java 5 there is a `PriorityQueue` implementation provided in the Java collections API:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

. . .

PriorityQueue nodes = new PriorityQueue<Node>(new NodeFComparator());
```

Comment: Will look into that, thx... however the a* openlist does not need duplicate values.

Comment: Sorry, values with the same f-value i.e., values that compare equal. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: thx david. now I see what you mean... I did it with the comparator hack in the meantime, but I think your way is the more elegant one. next time I'll use a PriorityQueue.

Comment: turns out you are right about the PQ. using the TreeMap with the weird comparator suggested by tbodt and user3340630 works not really. first, the comparator breaks its contract by providing inconsistent values for transitivity. however this only surfaces when I use big maps with thousands of nodes. second, even on small maps the path search fails sometimes without a good reason. it gets stuck on some node because apparently the ordering is not right. using PQ instead all of this is fixed and best paths are found all the time!

Comment: @jackthehipster Thanks, Jack. Glad to hear it's working for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you can use ArrayList instead of TreeSet, since it won't remove items that are duplicates (according to the comparator that you pass it).

You can add your Nodes to an ArrayList, and when you're ready to sort it, invoke the method from the Collections class,

`Collections.sort(myList, myComparator)`

Comment: I know this will work, but it seems such a waste to sort that stupid list every single time a node is added... if I use large maps the performance can't be good!?

Comment: You can sort it when the list is finalized. But with modern CPUs, as long as your list isn't a million records long, you won't have to worry about performance. The key is to use the data structure which is best for your purposes. If you want constant-time lookup, you could use a HashMap, and convert that to a sorted list on the fly.

Comment: I do not agree with your statement. The performance is always important. If you do not care, the software sucks.

Comment: Ever hear "premature optimization is the root of all evil?" Of course performance is important, but as I said, if his lists aren't gigantic then they won't even impact the performance. One way to be sure is to benchmark it on the target machine. Make sure it's a real problem and not an imaginary one. There are probably plenty of other real problems that need attention.

Comment: @ktm: the list has to be sorted every time it changes, because the algorithm always needs to access the node with the lowest-f-value (=the most promising one). you are right, for small maps it would make little difference, but if I have a 1000*1000 map (which is not unusual for games), and lots of NPCs, it would suck badly pretty quickly. i just wanna get it right from the beginning...

Answer (score 2):

Just change your comparator a little:

```
public class NodeFComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node arg0, Node arg1) {
        int result = arg0.getF() - arg1.getF();
        if (result == 0)
            return arg0.hashCode() - arg1.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This will return correct results for nodes with different f-values, and when the nodes have the same f-values, they will be compared by their hash codes. You could use any other unique property other than the hash code for this, but I chose hash codes because they are almost unique and every object has them.

Comment: Yep, just like user3340630 suggested. I think this is the way to go. Thanks. Will try that and accept your answer asap!

Comment: I had to change the correct answer to David Conrad. Explanation is below his answer. In short: your way only works sometimes, but proves to be instable with large amounts of nodes (in other words, big maps). and also on smaller maps it can lead to buggy behaviour of the pathfinder. I strongly suggest not using that technique and instead use a PriorityQueue!

Answer (score 0):

If the compare method is not consistent with equals implementation you got be careful which collection classes you got to use. TreeSet is not a good choice here. One alternative would be look at Multimap implementations in Guava library https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap